# What's the Debian package name for GnuPG Shell?

Tags: gpg

As mentioned [here](https://gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.html) and also [here](https://www.sysadmin.md/gui-frontends-for-gnupg.html), **GnuPG Shell** is a GUI frontend for **GnuPG** (also called gpg or **G**nu **P**rivacy **G**uard), which is a GNU implementation of OpenPGP, (which is a rewrite of the original PGP).

Although there is a Debian package for GnuPG Shell available [here](https://www.tech-faq.com/gnupg-shell.shtml), I can't find a package for it in the Debian Repository by searching for 'GnuPG Shell', 'gpg-shell', 'gpgshell', gnupg-shell, ... etc.

**Is it actually in the Debian repository?**  If so what's the name there?

If not why not?  Is there some security problem with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Tried installing the tech-faq.com deb file:  
  
`$ sudo dpkg -i gnupgshell-1.0.0.i386.deb     
Selecting previously unselected package gnupgshell:i386.  
(Reading database ... 554563 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack gnupgshell-1.0.0.i386.deb ...  
Unpacking gnupgshell:i386 (1.0.0-1) ...  
Setting up gnupgshell:i386 (1.0.0-1) ...  `
  
but something is wrong.  First no man page, from `man -k gnupg`  .
Also can't find binary, nor xdg menu item for it.  

Now to remove it cleanly with snapper.

Recommend AGAINST using the tech-faq.com *.deb file.

Comment: It put this file on my system:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4225124 Oct 13  2007 /usr/bin/wxGnuPGShell`

If run it gives:

`# /usr/bin/wxGnuPGShell 
/usr/bin/wxGnuPGShell: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

???

Comment: Also this was in /var/lib/dpkg/status:  

` * watchgnupg -- watch socket-based logs
 Homepage: https://www.gnupg.org/`
 
`+Package: gnupgshell
+Status: install ok installed
+Priority: extra
+Section: Security
+Installed-Size: 4684
+Maintainer: will.spencer@tech-faq.com
+Architecture: i386
+Version: 1.0.0-1
+Description: GnuPG Shell
+
 Package: gnustep-base-common
 Status: install ok installed
 Priority: optional`

Comment: So, BOTTOM LINE, I think this is an old .deb file and should not be used.

Comment: Install `libgtk2.0-0:i386` and `libgtk2.0-0:i386` then run `sudo wxGnuPGShell`

Comment: @GAD3R, Already had libgtk2.0-0 installed, not sure about ':386' architecture. ... kind of really old architecture; like 20 years since I've had a 386.  Also looks like this .deb is version 1.0.0 which doesn't sound good.  I think I'm done messing with this.  BTW,  `KGpg`, `gpa`, and `seahorse` (aka `Passwords and Keys`) all seem to work better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This package is not available in the Debian repository. Download it from the [website](https://www.tech-faq.com/gnupg-shell/gnupgshell-1.0.0.i386.deb.gz) and install it from the source or use the provided .deb binary.

I don't have much idea about why this is not available in the official repo. Guess people don't use this much, perhaps?

Comment: I pretty much knew all this before.  Sometimes the application and the package have somewhat different names, which can make it not so findable in the Debian repository.  Other times certain apps have been deliberately removed from the Debian repository for cause.  I'm really looking for the answers to either of my main first or 2nd questions.  Thanks though.  Say well brother.